# Can't run a suite of test for PhpSpec code coverage on jenkins file

Tags: php, jenkins, code-coverage, phpspec

I'm running a jenkins job to report the code coverage for my php spec tests.

My problem is that I have two separate path for those tests and I want to report the code coverage for both of them. Since php spec doesn't let you specify a suite of tests on the command executed at the jenkins job the only way I found for this, is just having different coverage.yml files.

Comment: What do you mean with " Since php spec doesn't let you specify a suite of tests"?

Comment: Php spec let you specify a suit of tests on the config files, then when you run the tests it runs the suit of tests(when they are on different paths). But when you run the command in the jenkins job you can't config this file.

Comment: You can specify aswell as argument, I think. Why wouldn't this be possible?

Comment: Because you cant specify two different path.